# Contraction proof of averaging operator: $\operatorname{Var}_\nu (M f) \leq (1 - \kappa)^2 \operatorname{Var}_\nu (f)$

Tags: operator-theory, variance, random-walk, contraction-operator

Let $(X, d, m)$ be an ergodic random walk on a metric space, with invariant distribution $\nu$. Suppose that the coarse Ricci curvature of $X$ is at least $\kappa > 0$ and that the average diffusion constant $\sigma$ verifies $\sigma < \infty$. Suppose that $\nu$ is reversible. For $f \in L^2(X, \nu)$, let the averaging operator $M$ be
$$
Mf(x) := \int_X f(y) \, \text{d}m_x(y).
$$
I am trying to prove that
$$
\operatorname{Var}_\nu(Mf) \leq (1 - \kappa)^2 \operatorname{Var}_\nu(f),
$$
inequality used in the proof of corollary 31 of Yann Ollivier's paper [Ricci curvature of Markov chains on metric spaces](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S002212360800493X?token=4F05E3DFEFAA4BA15A8F6C4CCE3C653E5B2FB6367F69A28B17291C66F8914FD28E464103DF88F2B55909B6891C5E77B4&originRegion=eu-west-1&originCreation=20210903161003).

I know that
$$
\operatorname{Var}_\nu (f) = \int_X \operatorname{Var}_{m_x} (f) \, \text{d}\nu(x) + \operatorname{Var}_\nu(Mf),
$$
and since the coarse Ricci curvature of $X$ is $\kappa$, for every $k$-Lipschitz function $f : X \mapsto R$, the function $Mf$ is $k(1 − \kappa)$-Lipschitz. Moreover, Lipschitz functions are dense in $L^2(X, \nu)$. Finally, I know that the spectral radius of the averaging operator $M$ acting on $L^2(X, \nu)/\{ \text{const} \}$ is at most $1 - \kappa$. However, I am still unsure how to justify that
$$
\operatorname{Var}_\nu(Mf) \leq (1 - \kappa)^2 \operatorname{Var}_\nu(f).
$$

Comment: The use of `\text{}` rather than `\operatorname{}` is the reason why the spacing between $(1-\kappa)^2$ and $\operatorname{Var}$ was smaller than it should be. This does not mean simply that the latter results in more space; rather with the latter the spacing varies with the context.

Comment: I see, thank you @MichaelHardy!